# Obtain the latest refspec on a Gerrit Change

Tags: git, ssh, gerrit, refspec

How can I obtain the latest refspec on a gerrit change through a single command.
I need the output as "refs/changes/11/1234/4". Is there any git command for the same

I do know that ssh commands combined with gerrit query and a bit of scripting can obtain this, but want to know if there is any better way to do the same. Following is the ssh command I would use to get the refspec.

ssh -p $REVIEW_SERVER_PORT $GERRIT_REVIEW_SERVER gerrit query --format=TEXT --current-patch-set $CHANGE_SHA  | grep ref.

Similarly, I would also want to get the LATEST PATCHSET of the gerrit change

Comment: Did you ever find your answer?  I'm also looking for something like this.

Answer (score 13):

You should use the [gerrit query](https://review.openstack.org/Documentation/cmd-query.html). Given change number `4665`:

```
ssh -p 29418 review.example.com gerrit query --current-patch-set --format=JSON change:4665
```

Which outputs:

```
{  
   "project":"xx",
   "branch":"master",
   "topic":"TOPIC",
   "id":"I0b6fc492fd08749e409c359a73d74e7795f50cc9",
   "number":"4665",
   // ...
   "currentPatchSet":{  
      "number":"5",
      "revision":"ae3a5d2684991070041e1c34b5a16b1376dc3ce5",
      "parents":[  
         "5b21793cadd3dc55008ef6c8dc658e127d80c097"
      ],
      "ref":"refs/changes/65/4665/5",
      // ...
   }
}
```

where you can find the `currentPatchSet.ref` field.

---

**Old, overcomplicated solution:**

Provided that you want to get the latest patchset of change `2392`:

```
git ls-remote | grep /2392/ | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/\// /g' | sort -n -k5 | tail -n 1 | sed 's/ /\//g'
```

which outputs `refs/changes/92/2392/12` for my repo.

Or, when you want to get the last Change from the Gerrit:

```
git ls-remote | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/\// /g' | sort -n -k4 | tail -n 1 | sed 's/ /\//g'
```

which outputs `refs/changes/54/2554/2` for my repo.

---

**Explanation**

[git ls-remote](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-ls-remote.html) command displays all references in a remote repository, so in case of Gerrit - every patchset is listed too. It outputs something like:

```
2ccddbfb34a98e8ba461964fae3766aa41be944d        refs/changes/91/2291/7
d00c21c28d07626caea27594489442696ea39231        refs/changes/91/2291/8
8c05e6551a6a34c33a36669bf7e83c996569e24d        refs/changes/91/2291/9
bc6762ac7b9ac5a74fc2e548df2541cb83977ec5        refs/changes/91/2391/1
3bd96c0d1ba2d561fa484ddfc264fabbf86aa536        refs/changes/91/2391/2
```

So in order to pick all patchsets from a particular change, we need to grep results out by `/NUMBER/`, which explains the `grep /2392/`. After that and by selecting second column with [awk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK), the result is:

```
refs/changes/92/2392/1
refs/changes/92/2392/10
refs/changes/92/2392/11
refs/changes/92/2392/12
refs/changes/92/2392/2
refs/changes/92/2392/3
refs/changes/92/2392/4
refs/changes/92/2392/5
refs/changes/92/2392/6
refs/changes/92/2392/7
refs/changes/92/2392/8
refs/changes/92/2392/9
```

Now we want to pick the last patchset. We need sorting. [sort](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_sort.htm) command is able to sort by a numbers with `-n` and we can specify on which column to perform sorting with `-kX` argument. But it requires columns to be separated with white space (AFAIK), so we need to replace our `/` delimiters with a space. We use [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) for it. After first replacement, each `refs/changes/92/2392/X` becomes `refs changes 92 2392 X`. Then sort is performed on fifth column (patchset number). Result:

```
refs changes 92 2392 1
refs changes 92 2392 2
refs changes 92 2392 3
refs changes 92 2392 4
refs changes 92 2392 5
refs changes 92 2392 6
refs changes 92 2392 7
refs changes 92 2392 8
refs changes 92 2392 9
refs changes 92 2392 10
refs changes 92 2392 11
refs changes 92 2392 12
```

Last thing to do is to select the last line with [tail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_(Unix)) and replace the spaces back to be slashes. Voilà!

Selecting latest change from Gerrit is done in the same way, but without grep and sorting by fourth column (Change-Id).

Comment: Once can replace `sed 's/\// /g' | sort -n -k5 | tail -n 1 | sed 's/ /\//g'` with `sort -t'/' -k5rn | head -1`

Comment: Adding  `| jq '.currentPatchSet.ref'` would make this answer more usable.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that would work over HTTP as SSH may not work in some CI environments.

```
find_latest_change () {
  local remote=$1
  local review=$2
  git ls-remote $remote | grep -E "refs/changes/[[:digit:]]+/$2/" | sort -t / -k 5 -g | tail -n1 | awk '{print $2}'
}

remote=https://review.gerrithub.io/org-name/project-name
latest=$(find_latest_change $remote 12345)
git fetch $remote $latest && git cherry-pick FETCH_HEAD
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that avoids listing the remote or using the gerrit REST API.

Every change in gerrit has a special ref called `meta`:

```
git fetch origin refs/changes/98/898/meta
```

Once fetched, it points to a chain of commits that represent the history of updates to this change. The commit message, among other things, has a trailer `Patch-set` that will contain the patchset number this change applies to:

```
> git log FETCH_HEAD

Author: Gerrit User 1000026 <1000026@dc17d2f6-4abc-4304-ba32-8b7ca44eda6b>
Date:   Wed Aug 19 06:36:23 2020 +0100

Update patch set 6

Change has been successfully cherry-picked as 68e4bc1612d61110ccfae4ac94bbd4458b2868a9 by Leonid Usov

Patch-set: 6
Subject: Add a new feature
Status: merged
Commit: 68e4bc1612d61110ccfae4ac94bbd4458b2868a9
Tag: autogenerated:gerrit:merged
Groups: bd9a33f7432c39308935056720de59168ff04003
Label: Code-Review=+2
Label: Verified=+1 Gerrit User 1000001 <1000001@dc17d2f6-4abc-4304-ba32-8b7ca44eda6b>
Label: SUBM=+1
Submission-id: 914
Submitted-with: OK
Submitted-with: OK: Code-Review: Gerrit User 1000026 <1000026@dc17d2f6-4abc-4304-ba32-8b7ca44eda6b>
Submitted-with: OK: Verified: Gerrit User 1000001 <1000001@dc17d2f6-4abc-4304-ba32-8b7ca44eda6b>
```

Naturally, the tip of that branch will point to the latest update, and hence will contain the number of the latest patchset. Here is how I can know the latest patch set number of a change:

```
 » git fetch origin refs/changes/14/914/meta \
   && git cat-file -p FETCH_HEAD \
    | git interpret-trailers --parse \
    | sed -E "/^Patch-set:/s/([[:alpha:]-]+):[[:space:]]*(.*)/\2/;q"
From ssh://gerrit/repo
 * branch                    refs/changes/14/914/meta -> FETCH_HEAD
6
```

Feel free to use that `6` on the stdout as you please ;)